# Which Azure AD option to use for a multitenant app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multitenant SAAS web app in Azure and I am a bit confused which option from Azure AD I should use. The requirement is to be able to easily create new tenants programmatically as there can be a lot of them. Should each tenant has its own Azure AD B2C instance or there should be one instance for all such tenants? Or should I search for some better options than Azure AD?

I have found the following sample: https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2017/07/27/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/ but I'm not sure if it is a preferred approach.

Comment: More detail, please. Multi-tenant SaaS apps can be used by any Azure AD tenant. Why do you need to create them? And why do you need B2C?

Comment: Multitenant app in Azure AD aims to allow users in these tenants to log in and access their own data without creating App registration in each tenant.  It seems that your understanding of the concept is rather vague. Create new tenants programmatically has nothing to do with using multi-tenant applications. So, what exactly are your needs? Please provide more details.

Comment: To be more precise: some companies may not have/use azure ad. They are valid customers for my app. How should they be treated? By creating B2C tenant for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a misunderstanding of multi-tenant app and Azure B2C.

Firstly, if you want to implement multi-tenant app, all your customers should have their own AAD tenants. Then you can add your app registration (as an enterprise app) into their tenants so that they can use your multi-tenant app.

See official guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant).

Secondly, it is also feasible if you want to use Azure B2C. It will require you to implement B2C authentication in your application. You should have an Azure B2C tenant for this. But your customers don't need to own B2C tenant and they also don’t even need to have an AAD tenant.

Azure B2C allows your customers to sign up to your B2C as local account and log into your application. It is exactly what B2C does.

You can look into the [B2C document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/).